# Parallel writes/reads in a single nio selector

Tags: java, io, nio

I am working on java.nio which mentions that nio is non blocking io as it is mentioned in the below example.

```
int noOfKeys = selector.select();
System.out.println("Number of selected keys: " + noOfKeys);
Set selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
Iterator iter = selectedKeys.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    SelectionKey ky = iter.next();
    if (ky.isAcceptable()) {
        // Accept the new client connection
        SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
        client.configureBlocking(false);
        // Add the new connection to the selector
        client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        System.out.println("Accepted new connection from client: " + client);
    }
    else if (ky.isReadable()) {
        // Read the data from client
```

Everywhere i am seeing an loop which checks for readable keys and writable keys condition and continue with non blocking write/read. Is is possible to process two writes/reads simultaneously in a loop with as single selector? Any help or pointers are really helpful. Also For a socket connection first it should accept the connection then it should perform write or read. How come it is non blocking io? Is this sequential right?

Answer (score 3):

Non-blocking I/O is not the same parallel I/O.  What non-blocking I/O allows is I/O without blocking the calling thread.  Normally, the thread would wait on the system call to complete, which prevents the calling thread from doing any other work.  With non-blocking I/O, if the operation would block, it's deferred to allow the calling thread to do other work (e.g. other reads/writes/accepts).

You can use actual separate threads for I/O and do more than one I/O operation simultaneously, but typically there are more clients performing I/O than there are CPUs.  As the number of threads for each I/O set increases above the number of CPUs, they start contending for time on a CPU, which the operating system has to schedule.  So, each I/O operation starts to imply a context switch, which is expensive.  This additional cost, as well as other various costs, are the reason why parallel I/O generally doesn't perform well or scale.

Still, non-blocking I/O can conceptually be thought of as asynchronous or parallel since an operation that would normally block doesn't, and allows another I/O operation to run instead.  So, the actual operations overlap.  However, since they run in the same thread, it avoids that context switch costs and other various costs for parallel I/O.

In reality it is sequential though, and time spent executing application code on response to I/O does add to latency.  Generally that amount of time is less than a context switch though, which means non-blocking I/O normally performs and scales vastly better than parallel I/O.

With Java non-blocking I/O, you use the selector to do the multiplexing.  So, `selector.select()` retrieves all the clients that are ready to do I/O without blocking.  This is why you register the client's channel with the selector.  You're telling the selector that you want to know when it's ready to do I/O without blocking.

Also, just a note but *NIO* only stands for *New I/O*.  Non-blocking I/O is only a subset.

The Wikipedia descriptions aren't that good, but they might help...

- [Non-blocking I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O)
- [Java Non-blocking I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29)